# In angular, how to use cancel an $interval on user events, like page change?

Tags: angularjs

[Angular documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$interval) about `$interval` is saying :

> Note: Intervals created by this service must be explicitly destroyed when you are finished with them.

but it's not explaining how to destroy the $interval.

If for example I have a directive containing this code :

```
$interval(function() {
    for (var i in myArray) {
        // do domething
    }
}, 5000);
```

How can i destroy it when the user changes the page for example?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Whenever the user changes the page, the scope associated with the controller of the route (`/page1` in the example below) will be sent [a `$destroy` event](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#events_%24destroy). You can `cancel` that `$interval` in a listener to that event:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
     $routeProvider.when('/page1', {
          template: '<div>Page Content</div>',
          controller: PageController
      });
     // ...
});

function PageController($scope, $interval) {
    var intervalPromise = $interval(function () { /* ... */ }, 5000);      
    $scope.$on('$destroy', function () { $interval.cancel(intervalPromise); });
}
```

Comment: What about when you want to cancel/pause the $interval when the scope is changed to a child scope? the  $scope.$on('$destroy',...) won't be called.

Comment: @CaioOliveira I am not sure I understand what you mean by "changed to a child scope"? Do you want to cancel the $interval as soon as _any_ child scope is created? If so, I fail to see the use case. What scenario do you have in mind?

Comment: I just think it's wrong to state that "whenever the user changes the page". A page can be changed without destroying the scope, like when you create a child scope. I had a similar scenario: I needed the parent scope to remain active, but had to pause an interval when changing to this child scope. Of course I could pause it where you create the child scope, but I thought it was an ugly way to handle it (you can forget to pause it somewhere). I couldn't find a solution for that.

I'm really new to Angular, so maybe I'm doing something  that doesn't agree with it's philosophy.

Comment: @CaioOliveira, I bumped into a situation where I would set a new $interval to fetch new data upon a successful `$http` call. (Keep the data fresh). But if the `$http` request is fired after the `$state` is changed, then the timer will be re-initialized, which "appears" as if the $interval is not being `$destroy`'ed. Example on Plnkr.co: http://plnkr.co/edit/uPV6kQcIgELPoTAdc7BG?p=preview