# How do I check which page I'm on, or which is the controller for the current page?

Tags: angularjs, routes, url-routing

I have a page in Angularjs, and I am using the routeProvider to control the pages and the URL's for them. (Part of) my routeProvider definition looks something like this:

```
$routeProvider.when("/", {
    redirectTo: "/Overview"
}).when("/Overview", {
    controller: "OverviewController",
    templateUrl:"template/overview.html"
}).when("/Group", {
    controller: "GroupController",
    templateUrl:"template/group.html"
});
```

The `OverviewController` shows markers for each group on Google Maps, and then `GroupController` shows markers for each user in the selected group.

Because users often change their position or status, the data in the `GroupController` is being refreshed every minute in an interval.

```
dataFactory.getUsers($routeParams.id);
$interval(function(){
    dataFactory.getUsers($routeParams.id);
}, 60*1000);
```

The `getUsers()` method in this case will fetch data via Ajax, and then call the appropriate method to show the markers on the map.

The problem occurs when you go to the `/Group` page once, and then navigate back to `/Overview`. The interval keeps executing, and the markers on the overview will get overwritten with the markers for the users in the previously viewed group.

I want to add a condition inside the function that's in the `$interval` call, that would check if we're on the `/Group` page. How would I do that in the Angular way? (instead of checking the `window.location.href` string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go to a different direction. You should stop your interval when leaving the page, instead of adding a condition.

```
var intervalPromise = $interval(function () { /* ... */ }, 5000);      
$scope.$on('$destroy', function () { $interval.cancel(intervalPromise); });
```

This will destroy your timer when you leave the controller.

[In angular, how to use cancel an $interval on user events, like page change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21364480/in-angular-how-to-use-cancel-an-interval-on-user-events-like-page-change)

Answer (score 0):

You can use $routeChangeStart to track that the page is being redirected to other page.

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(next, current) { 
   ... you could cancel your interval here ...
 });
```

OR

You can use any of below to track location change.

**$locationChangeStart** - fires before the location view-model and browser URL are synchronized.
**$locationChangeSuccess** - fires after the location view-model and the browser URL are synchronized.

```
$scope.$on("$locationChangeSuccess",function(event) {
     ... you could cancel your interval here ...
});
```