# Angular $destroy method not called on page navigation in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, timer, angularjs-scope, ondestroy

I have an application that uses both Angular and Ruby on Rails.  Some of my Angular controllers create $interval timers that need to be cancelled when the user navigates to a new page.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21364774/4714425) Stack Overflow answer, among others, says that the best solution is to insert the code below into the Angular controllers with the timer:

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function () { 
    $interval.cancel(timerName); 
});
```

However, when I do this and set a breakpoint in this code when debugging, the breakpoint is never reached.  This means that the `$destroy` event is never triggered on page changes.  I'm wondering how I can go about triggering this event, or if there is a better way to kill my timers when the user navigates to another page.

Comment: I have noticed that with Angular the breakpoints sometimes don't work.  Did you try replacing with a console.log to ensure it is not being hit?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it fits your need, but you can do this

1. Pull the $interval into a service.
2. Trigger the interval using the
   above service on the controller/route that you want to trigger.
3. Cancel the trigger using the service on route change